# Stuck on incorrect number of dimensions error when running lapply(data, function)

Tags: r

I am trying to run a function over a data.frame by row. The dataset is too large to include but here is a glimpse:

```
  patientid SBP Smoker DM TotChol HDL HTN Race      age gender
1        13 132      0  0     130  45   0    0 56.59954      1
2        21 150      0  1     154  52   1    1 54.19395      0
3        36 154      0  1     141  41   1    1 66.52546      0
4        45 126      0  1     134  48   1    0 67.00228      0
5        49 134      0  1     169  43   1    1 57.70091      1
6        50 136      0  0     168  35   0    0 49.18025      1
```

And here is my function:

```
ASCVD_calc <- function(ASCVD_10, gender_col = "gender", race_col = "Race", HTN_col = "HTN", age_col = "age", totchol_col = "TotChol",
    hdl_col = "HDL", sbp_col = "SBP", smoke_col = "Smoker", dm_col = "DM") {
     ##Coefficients are different for different gender, race or treatment status
     if ((ASCVD_10[, gender_col] == 0) & (ASCVD_10[, race_col] == 0) & (ASCVD_10[,htn_col] == 0) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] >= 40) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] < 80)) {
          param <- c(-29.799, 4.884, 13.540, -3.114, -13.578, 3.149, 1.957, 0, 7.574, -1.665, 0.661, -29.18, 0.9665)
     } 
     if ((ASCVD_10[, gender_col] == 0) & (ASCVD_10[, race_col] == 0) & (ASCVD_10[, htn_col] == 1) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] >= 40) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] < 80))  {
          param <- c(-29.799, 4.884, 13.540, -3.114, -13.578, 3.149, 2.019, 0, 7.574, -1.665, 0.661, -29.18, 0.9665)
     }
     if ((ASCVD_10[, gender_col] == 0) & (ASCVD_10[, race_col] == 1) & (ASCVD_10[, htn_col] == 0) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] >= 40) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] < 80)) {
          param <- c(17.114, 0, 0.94, 0, -18.920, 4.475, 27.820, -6.087, 0.691, 0, 0.874, 86.61, 0.9533)
     }
     if ((ASCVD_10[, gender_col] == 0) & (ASCVD_10[, race_col] == 1) & (ASCVD_10[, htn_col] == 1) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] >= 40) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] < 80)) {
          param <- c(17.114, 0, 0.94, 0, -18.920, 4.475, 29.291, -6.432, 0.691, 0, 0.874, 86.61, 0.9533)
     }
     if ((ASCVD_10[, gender_col] == 1) & (ASCVD_10[, race_col] == 0) & (ASCVD_10[, htn_col] == 0) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] >= 40) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] < 80)) {
          param <- c(12.344, 0, 11.853, -2.664, -7.990, 1.769, 1.764, 0, 7.837, -1.795, 0.658, 61.18, 0.9144)
     }
     if ((ASCVD_10[, gender_col] == 1) & (ASCVD_10[, race_col] == 0) & (ASCVD_10[, htn_col] == 1) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] >= 40) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] < 80)) {
          param <- c(12.344, 0, 11.853, -2.664, -7.990, 1.769, 1.797, 0, 7.837, -1.795, 0.658, 61.18, 0.9144)
     }
     if ((ASCVD_10[, gender_col] == 1) & (ASCVD_10[, race_col] == 1) & (ASCVD_10[, htn_col] == 0) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] >= 40) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] < 80)) {
          param <- c(2.469, 0, 0.302, 0, -0.307, 0, 1.809, 0, 0.549, 0, 0.645, 19.54, 0.8954)
     }
     if ((ASCVD_10[, gender_col] == 1) & (ASCVD_10[, race_col] == 1) & (ASCVD_10[, htn_col] == 1) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] >= 40) & (ASCVD_10[,age_col] < 80)) {
          param <- c(2.469, 0, 0.302, 0, -0.307, 0, 1.916, 0, 0.549, 0, 0.645, 19.54, 0.8954)
     }

     ##Transformed Risk Score Predictors
     pred_trans <- c(log(ASCVD_10[, age_col]), (log(ASCVD_10[, age_col])^2), log(ASCVD_10[, totchol_col]),
     log(ASCVD_10[, age_col])*log(ASCVD_10[, totchol_col]), log(ASCVD_10[, hdl_col]), log(ASCVD_10[, age_col])*log(ASCVD_10[, hdl_col]), 
     log(ASCVD_10[, sbp_col]), log(ASCVD_10[, age_col])*log(ASCVD_10[, sbp_col]), ASCVD_10[, smoke_col], log(ASCVD_10[, age])*ASCVD[, smoke_col],
     ASCVD_10[, dm_col])

     ##sum of the transformed variables multiplied by corresponding coefficients
     pred_sum <- sum(param[[1:11]]*pred_trans)

     ##Return ASCVD 10 Year Risk
     a <- exp(pred_sum - param[[12]])
     ASCVD_10$Risk10 <- paste(round((1 - (param[[13]]^a))*100,1),"%")
     return(ASCVD_10)
};

ASCVD_10$Risk10 <- apply(ASCVD_10, 1, ASCVD_calc);
```

But I keep getting this error message: `Error in ASCVD_10[, gender_col] : incorrect number of dimensions`I can't seem to figure out a way to get passed it.

Things I've already tried:

1. na.omit
2. ensuring that all of the columns of the data.frame contain
   the same number of records
3. ensuring that all of the records meet the criteria of
   one of the if statements
4. using lapply instead of apply

Thanks in advance for any clarification you can give.

Answer (score 3):

When using `apply()`, values are passed to your function as an atomic named vector; not as a data.frame. `apply()` is meant to be used with matrixes rather than `data.frames` so it's assumed that all columns/rows are of the same data.type. Since you are indexing via

```
ASCVD_10[, gender_col]
```

within your function, you get an error since `ASCVD_10` is a vector, not a data.frame. It is a named vector so you could do

```
ASCVD_10[gender_col]
```

This strategy seems difficult to maintain or scale. Seems like you want to perform different transformations for different subsets. Perhaps you are trying to predict from a previously fitted regression model? Rather than doing an `apply`, you might be better off splitting your data, doing the transformation, then recombining. It would help to describe what you're really trying to do rather than just showing how you tried to do it.

Comment: **Perhaps you are trying to predict from a previously fitted regression model?** You are correct! That is exactly what I am trying to do. If I understood you correctly, your recommendation would be to run the transformations on each subset of data and then recombine the subsets after transformation? Also, I converted the column names to vectors as you suggested and running the function no longer got caught at the same place, but instead I ran into the following error `Error in log(ASCVD_10[age_col]) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function` Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: well, it all depends on how you are getting the parameters. Are you fitting the models yourself? Are you copying them from a paper? Are you importing them from a file? It would be better to start a question with your actual programming challenge, rather than trying to hack at your solution.

Comment: The parameters are coming from [this paper](http://circ.ahajournals.org/content/early/2013/11/11/01.cir.0000437741.48606.98.full.pdf). And thank you for the advice on how to best craft my questions. I will make sure to give a clearer picture of my goal in the future.